# Extra \endgroup error with RevTeX after update

Tags: errors, revtex, updating

After today's update, when I try to use one of the RevTeX classes:

```latex
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}    
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {begindo...
l.3 \begin{document}
                    
?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: it will be repaired tomorrow. You could install a new revtex manually, or use the tlmgr backup facilities to revert to the previous latex version.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is not my lucky day then. Thank you for your quick reply! Should I then install REVTeX 4.2c? I also saw an issue with natbib on a file that was typeset before without issue. Will that be fixed as well or should I make it a separate question?

Comment: natbib? better show it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I extended the question rather than asking a new one  since a period of 40 min between questions is imposed.

Comment: you need revtex 4.2d it is on ctan (but perhaps not in all mirrors), it is missing a bst-file but the old one from your previous version should work. This is only temporary, tomorrow there should be 4.2e on ctan.

Comment: you can not use biblatex together with revtex, as it loads natbib (perhaps it has an option to suppress natbib but I doubt it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Which mirror do you recommend?

Comment: simply try one, but pay attention to the version number (and install so that you can remove it easily again when the fix is in texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated with the tex live utility but the error remains.

Comment: the new revtex did make it too late yesterday to ctan to get into texlive, it should be there tomorrow, (version 4.2e, it is already on ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Nice to know, thanks, and I can wait another day.

Comment: well I hope it is then there, if not get the tds,zip http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/revtex.tds.zip,unpack it somewhere (outside your texsystem) and add the root with `tlmgr conf auxtrees add path/to/root`

Comment: difficult birth, but today revtex was in the updates. So it should work now.

Comment: @my2cts Hi, sorry about the mess with RevTeX, it was mostly my fault. Glad to know it's working now. I edited your question to be more easily searchable (pictures of code/log are terrible) for future users, and removed the `biblatex` issue, which is unrelated.  Hope it's okay.

Comment: Thanks to the team for their good work!

Comment: I'm also having the same problem as of 10th of Oct 2020.
Is it fixed already?
How can I fix it?

Comment: hellbourne, Phelype Oleinik.
Nothing strange - it never worked. user226462 and me already reported about it, but our reports are simply ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved in RevTex 4.2e.