# Extra endgroup error at begin document after Oct 2020 update : how to pinpoint faulty package?

Tags: updating

In a fashion similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565215/extra-endgroup-error-with-revtex-after-update) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565937/catoptions-menukeys-packages-compilation-error/566042) question, I now get a "Extra endgroup" error at the `\begin{document}` of documents that previously compiled fine.

I understand this is because of [the new LaTeX update](https://www.latex-project.org//news/2020/10/01/issue32-of-latex2e-released/) that inter alia changed the `AtBeginDocument` hook to integrate it into a more systematic hook scheme.

So I suspect one of the very numerous packages I am using is not (yet) compatible. I reverted to an earlier version of LaTeX as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566042/) (also had to revert eso-pic).

How can I pinpoint which package(s) is at fault ? This seems hard to me because the faulty constructions are added to the hook and everything explodes at `\begin{document}`.

How can I inspect the content of what is to be done at that point and what should I look for ? I used to use `\show` to explore what is going on, often needing a `\makeatletter` to get to internal commands, but now the internals of `\UseOneTimeHook` are in the new syntax eg. `\hook_use_one:n` and I cannot `\show` it at the latex prompt.

Comment: You can use `\csname` to build any control sequence (even if it includes spaces) in the following way: `\expandafter\show\csname hook_use_one:n\endcsname`. Also you can use `\ExplSyntaxOn` like you use `\makeatletter` to get the category codes for `\show\hook_use_one:n`.

Comment: The incompatible packages are not that many, so if you add `\listfiles` at the top of your document and show us the file list, it should be easy to pinpoint the faulty package.  However, the error happens before the `begindocument` hook: the faulty packages break because they redefine `\document`, so if you use `\show\document` you can have a clue of which package did the redefinition.  Looking at the definition of `\hook_use_once:n` will not help here

Comment: Thank you so much. Here is the list of files : https://framagit.org/-/snippets/5992.

Comment: xwatermark/catoptions

Comment: Thanks. I can dispose of xwatermark for a reasonable amount of time, but menukeys also uses catopions and I regularly need it, so I will cross my fingers that either of them gets an update.

Comment: @ysalmon You can try the workaround I suggested [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/411#issuecomment-708434918), if it works for `menukeys` (the workaround is not exactly robust, so depending which parts of `catoptions` are used, it may or may not work).

Comment: Thanks ; it seems to work. I love how you are using the same hook mechanism that causes catoptions to break in order to fix it! This new hook scheme looks very nice.