# Extra \endgroup error after transforming \documentclass{article} into \documentclass{revtex4-2}

Tags: errors, revtex, documentclass

Can you please help me identify what is wrong with my coding? I've searched online for solutions but I couldn't find a working one. Before, I used `article` for my `\documentclass` to complete my thesis. Now, they required me to use `revtex4-2` as the `\documentclass`. So, I modified some of the lines from the coding but it keeps on giving me errors probably because some of the packages don't work in the `revtex4-2` class but I couldn't figure out what.

Here is my preamble for the coding:

```
\documentclass[%  
 aip,  
% jmp,  
% bmf,  
% sd,  
% rsi,  
cp,  % Conference Proceedings  
 amsmath,amssymb,%nobibnotes,  
% preprint,%  
 reprint,%  
%author-year,%  
%author-numerical,%  
]{revtex4-2}  

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files  
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point  
\usepackage{bm}% bold math  
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math  
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
%% Loads a Times-like font. You can also load  
%% {newtxtext,newtxtmath}, but not {times},   
%% {txfonts} nor {mathtpm} as these packages  
%% are obsolete and have been known to cause problems.  
\usepackage{mathptmx}   

\usepackage{paralist}  
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}  
\usepackage{lscape}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage{slashbox}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage[hmarginratio=2:3]{geometry}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{afterpage}  
\usepackage{changepage}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{makecell}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{algorithmic}  
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{placeins}  
\usepackage{afterpage}  
\usepackage{url}  
\allowdisplaybreaks  
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}  
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}  
\newcommand{\dv}{\mid}  
\newcommand{\ndv}{\nmid}  
\citestyle{apa}  
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  

\begin{document}
```

Here's the error notification:

> ! Extra \endgroup.
> \document -> \endgroup
> \document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {begindo...

Sorry if my information isn't enough because I'm still new here. I don't know what else to provide you with. Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: probably mixed version dates of latex/packages. Ensure that everything is up-to-date. If you use miktex update in user *and* admin mode in the miktex console.

Comment: I already updated it from the MiKTeX Console but the error is still there.

Comment: Run a small document which loads only the class. It the errors show the complete log file

Comment: Welcome, @AzmadiM! I'd like to iterate upon @UlrikeFischer's comment: at the very top of your document, try adding the ```\listfiles``` command. When compiling the document, it will display the versions of all the used packages, along with the version of the document class. In that console output, what version is mentioned for ```revtex4-2.cls```? Is it anything other than **4.2e**? On my device, it says ```revtex4-2.cls  2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)```. The answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565864/256551 is the reason I ask about this version.

Comment: Hello @MiriamBriskman. Sorry for the late reply. I have looked on it like what you said. The one on my device says "\revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2018/12/26/16:06:17 4.2b (https://journals.aps.org/re
vtex/ for documentation)" How to update to 4.2e? I think it is the problem.

Comment: @AzmadiM, this is OK! Just to confirm: when you open the ```MiKTeX``` console, and go to the ```Updates``` tab on the left-hand side, do you see ```revtex``` as one of the available updates (after you click on ```Check for updates```? You may need to scroll a bit to find it if it is there.) If yes, confirm that the version of ```revtex``` under the ```Available``` column is ```4.2e```, and proceed with the installation by clicking on ```Update Now``` [You may uncheck other packages from being installed.] Let me know if this is not the case, as we can alternatively do a manual install.

Comment: Hello @MiriamBriskman No the revtex isn't available for update since I already updated it before I posted the question here. It says "There are currently no updates available" I'm not sure whether the version I updated before is the 4.2e though.

Comment: Hi @AzmadiM. Thank you! I see. You can check the current version of ```revtex``` inside the Console by clicking on the ```Packages``` tab on the left side. On that page, enter ```revtex``` into the search (filter) bar, and click on the small funnel icon to see the results for ```revtex```. Afterward, right-click ```revtex``` and choose "Package Information". You will then see the version of the currently-installed ```revtex``` package. Is that version number ```4.2e``` or ```4.2b```, as you saw earlier during compilation?

Comment: Hey there @MiriamBriskman I've checked on the package information. The version number is 4.2e.

Comment: @AzmadiM, thank you very much for your reply! It is great to hear that ```4.2e``` is installed inside your user's account. Could you, please, also re-open the ```MiKTeX``` console, but this time by right-clicking and choosing ```Run as administrator``, and check the version of ```revtex``` there too? As @UlrikeFischer explained, ```MiKTeX``` installs packages separately for each user, but some packages are installed for all the users. As such, we need to ensure that the version of ```revtex``` is ```4.2e``` in that general installation or, if not, update it. Let me know what you see.

Comment: I created a document containing only `Hello` with your preamble.  I got an error about not having the  `slashbox` package.  It turns out that the `slashbox` package has been superseded by the diagmac2 package.  So I commented out the `\usepackage{slashbox}` line and added `\usepackage{diagmac2}` and I got no errors.

Comment: @MiriamBriskman Sorry again for the late reply, I was on a flight yesterday. I already ran MikTex Console & checked on the revtex information as you told me before & the version is 4.2e as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response @MátéWierdl I've edited the \usepackage{slashbox} out & replaced it with \usepackage{diagmac2} yet I still have the same error.

Comment: Here's a link to a screen capture of my Console output tab in TeXworks regarding the errors. I don't know if it helps but who knows you might see something I don't.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTrhPZpZUXssA24g_49pMOTQTSb4dFPz/view

Comment: Hi @AzmadiM; thank you very much for your reply and for letting us know. The interesting aspect in the situation is that the ```\listfiles``` command shows that ```4.2b``` is the version, while the ```MiKTeX``` Console shows it's ```4.2e```. The ```pdfLaTeX``` compiler in the video you took uses libraries at ```C:\Users\madie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\```. However, inside the ```MiKTeX``` Console under ```Settings``` > ```Directories```, what ```Path``` is displayed for ```Install```, ```User```? This question's intention is to rule out the case of multiple installs of ```MiKTeX```.

Comment: Hello @MiriamBriskman It's in the same path. C:\Users\madie\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTeX Yep I agree I found it weird since you pointed out in your comment about the \listfiles command. It's 4.2b in the Console output but in MikTex Console, it's 4.2e. I downloaded the template from this website. https://math.upm.edu.my/icmss2022/index.php/call-for-papers/template-for-abstract/

Comment: I also tried running the code at Overleaf. The online editor managed to compile my PDF but it's in landscape mode instead of portrait mode. If you don't mind me asking, do you have any idea on how to change the orientation? That aside, there's an error about the "Extra \endgroup" as well. Also, I would like to point out that there's a package called "revtex4" other than "revtex" in the MikTeX Console's Packages tab too & the category is listed as \Uncategorized. Is this normal or it is probably the cause of error.

Comment: @AzmadiM, I see. Thank you! When you copy the preamble into a new ```TeX``` document, and make the body be as short as ```\begin{document}  Foo \end{document}```, does the compilation of that new document produce the same ```Extra \endgroup``` error? Try the method at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354/256551 to change orientation. I too see the ```revtex4``` package as uncategorized on my device as you do, so most likely it is not related to the error.

Comment: @MiriamBriskman There isn't any error but it says "Sorry, but "MikTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed." Also, there are two warnings:

Class revtex4-2 Warning: Repair the float package.

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Comment: Does the new TeX document needs to be in the same folder as before? I've copied the new TeX file into the folder with the original file & it gave the same error. @MiriamBriskman The previous comment is when the new file is outside of the original file's folder.

Comment: @AzmadiM, thank you very much for your reply! The compilation video from your previous comment shows that the ```revtex``` library (```revtex4-2.cls```) at the location ```C:\Users\madie\Dropbox/PC/Downloads/FYP/TO BE PUBLISHED/ConfTemplate-20211114T010429X-001``` was used during compilation. However, the ```revtex``` library that should be used must be the one at ```C:\Users\madie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex\```. As such, can you (temporarily) move the ```FYP``` folder from ```Downloads``` to a different folder, and then re-compile the doc? What does the console show?

Comment: In addition, if the ```C:\Users\madie\Dropbox/PC/Downloads/FYP/TO BE PUBLISHED/ConfTemplate-20211114T010429X-001``` folder is where you are trying to run the document from, could you remove the ```revtex4-2.cls``` files from this folder away to a different temporary folder? If your current folder contains ```revtex4-2.cls```, it will be used instead of the updated ```MiKTeX``` version of ```revtex```. Perhaps, this "local" copy of ```revtex4-2.cls``` is the reason for the error, which also explains the different error messages across the different folders.

Comment: Where is the whole latex file?  I only see the preamble in the post without anything beyond `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Hello @MátéWierdl I think the error is mainly caused by the preamble because I managed to run the same latex coding beyond the \begin{document} before but now it has errors since I've changed the \documentclass . Besides, I wasn't sure if it's okay to share the whole latex file here. I've already solved the error by the way because of the revtex4-2.cls is in the folder that I'm working with probably because it is outdated?

Comment: Hello @MiriamBriskman you're a lifesaver! I've fixed it thank you so much! Yes, the revtex4-2.cls is the reason for the error. I've removed it from the folder I'm working with & it works wonder after that. I didn't realize the compiler uses the revtex4-2.cls in that folder. Maybe it is outdated since I downloaded it from the website. Thank you so much again for a very helpful guidance for the past few days. Sorry if I wasn't replying fast enough.

Comment: @AzmadiM, this is so great to hear! Congratulations on successfully solving the issue, and best of luck with writing your thesis work! The underlying issue was extremely delicate and, therefore, difficult to find, but you did it! With your permission, I will outline the path towards the solution, including the attempts that were made and the attempt that eventually succeeded, as an answer to the question. Hopefully, it will help other ```TeX``` users who encounter a similar issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First, we describe what action eliminated the error and then explain how we discovered the source of the error.

---

### Solution

The folder where the `TeX` document was located contained a copy of an old version of the `revtex` class document, `revtex4-2.cls`. During compilation, this old package was loaded by `pdfLaTeX`, which caused the `! Extra \endgroup.` error to appear.

**Removing the local copy of `revtex4-2.cls` away from the folder eliminated the error and let the document compile smoothly after the removal.**

---

### Diagnosing the Issue

The `TeX` document uses `revtex4-2` as the `\documentclass`.

The error

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document -> \endgroup
\document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {begindo...
```

which was generated during compilation, is produced when a `revtex4-2` version older than **4.2e** is loaded. This error is asked upon and answered by **my2cts** at [Extra \endgroup error with RevTeX after update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565215/extra-endgroup-error-with-revtex-after-update).

In general, to remove the error, one should proceed to update the package version. In `MiKTeX`, for example, the update should be done both at the user level and at the administrator level, as the answer by **Ulrike Fischer** to [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation) thoroughly explains.

However, the solution was not as easy as updating the package.

The [`MiKTeX` Console](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) showed that the currently installed version was **4.2e**, the most recent version of the package and that there are no pending updates for the package.

Nonetheless, including the command `\listfiles` at the top of the document, led to the following metadata output about the package:

```
\revtex4-2.cls Document Class: revtex4-2 2018/12/26/16:06:17 4.2b (journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
```

The loading of this older version (**4.2b**) of the `revtex` package into `pdfLaTeX`, given the verified installation of the newest version, indicated the presence of an older class document file elsewhere on the device.

---

### Searching for the old-version class document file

The log file showed that the majority of the loaded packages during compilation are in

```
C:\Users\madie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex
```

It was confirmed via the `MiKTeX` Console (under `Settings` > `Directories`) that `MiKTeX` installs user packages at the above directory.

However, the document class `revtex4-2.cls` was loaded from the external-to-the-installation directory

```
C:\Users\madie\Dropbox/PC/Downloads/FYP/TO BE PUBLISHED/ConfTemplate-20211114T010429X-001
```

It turned out this is the directory where the `TeX` file under question is placed.

`pdfLaTeX` used this local, old-version copy of `revtex4-2.cls` instead of the `MiKTeX`-installed version, because a copy of a `.tex`, `.sty`, `.cls`, etc. file that is located in the same folder as the `TeX` document overshadows the 'official' file in the installation path.

---

### Thanks

I would like to thank **Azmadi**, the writer of the question, for the responsiveness and the provision of the details that were crucial for detecting the issue.

The precious advice of **Ulrike Fischer** on confirming that the package was updated on `MiKTeX`, on the correct manner to execute updates, and on the great suggestion of reducing the `TeX` file to a minimal working example aided significantly in the error-finding process.

The recommendation of **Máté Wierdl** to replace the outdated `slashbox` package with `diagmac2` will undoubtedly eliminate errors and warnings related to the former package. Thank you very much for your input.